# Python Typing: TypedDict - What's the difference between TypedDict instance and TypedDict Class?

Tags: python, type-hinting

I'm trying to use Type Hinting to prevent myself from accidentally using wrong `dict` keys, which is working fine. However, I haven't been able to understand the difference between these two behaviors:

```
someType = TypedDict('someName', {'key': type})
```

and

```
class someType(TypedDict):
    key: type
```

From what I've tried, both of them yield the same results in type hinting. When I search online on how to use a TypedDict, all examples I see are for the 2nd case. But whenever I search for documentation, I find it only for the first case. I tried looking at previous StackOverflow questions but they seem to address TypedDict vs NamedTuple.

Comment: "But whenever I search for documentation, I find it only for the first case." - I don't know where you're looking, but the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypedDict) *only* show the second form. You'd have to look in the [PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0589/#alternative-syntax) to see the first form.

Comment: both cases are mentioned in the docs. These are equivalent: " To allow using this feature with older versions of Python that do not support PEP 526, TypedDict supports two additional equivalent syntactic forms"

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/more_types.html#totality This is that pops up to me whenever I search

Comment: @Amir can you repeat that but as an answer instead of a comment? This way I can approve your response!

Comment: @thethiny: [Scroll down.](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/more_types.html#class-based-syntax)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first syntax can be backported to older Python versions such as 3.5 and 2.7
that don't support the variable definition syntax. It resembles the traditional syntax for defining named tuples
Difference:
The semantics are equivalent to the class-based syntax. **This syntax doesn't support inheritance*

```
from typing import TypedDict

class Movie(TypedDict):
    name: str
    year: int
    

class_dict=Movie(name="John Wick", year=2014)

print(class_dict)
Movie2 = TypedDict('Movie', {'name': str, 'year': int})

print(Movie2(name="John Wick",year=2017))
```